# How to use ng2-table

Tags: angular, typescript

I had a very hard time working on it but no use...it says the error as 
Cannot read property 'match' of undefined.Can anyone please suggest some help..........

My ts,

```
    rows: Array<any> = [];
  columns: Array<any> = [
    {title: 'Name', name: 'accountname'},
  ];
  page: number = 1;
  itemsPerPage: number = 10;
  maxSize: number = 5;
  numPages: number = 1;
  length: number = 0;

  config: any = {
    paging: false,
    sorting: {columns: this.columns},
    filtering: {filterString: '', columnName: 'position'}
  };

  ng2TableData: Array<any> = this.students;

  constructor(public http:Http) { console.log(this.students);
    this.length = this.ng2TableData.length;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getstudents();
    this.onChangeTable(this.config);
  }

  changePage(page: any, data: Array<any> = this.ng2TableData): Array<any> {
    let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;
    let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 ? (start + page.itemsPerPage) : data.length;
    return data.slice(start, end);
  }

  changeSort(data: any, config: any): any {
    if (!config.sorting) {
      return data;
    }

    let columns = this.config.sorting.columns || [];
    let columnName: string = void 0;
    let sort: string = void 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
      if (columns[i].sort !== '' && columns[i].sort !== false) {
        columnName = columns[i].name;
        sort = columns[i].sort;
      }
    }

    if (!columnName) {
      return data;
    }

    // simple sorting
    return data.sort((previous: any, current: any) => {
      if (previous[columnName] > current[columnName]) {
        return sort === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
      } else if (previous[columnName] < current[columnName]) {
        return sort === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }

  changeFilter(data: any, config: any): any {
    if (!config.filtering) {
      return data;
    }

    let filteredData: Array<any> = data.filter((item: any) =>
      item[config.filtering.columnName].match(this.config.filtering.filterString));

    return filteredData;
  }

  onChangeTable(config: any, page: any = {page: this.page, itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage}): any {
    if (config.filtering) {
      Object.assign(this.config.filtering, config.filtering);
    }
    if (config.sorting) {
      Object.assign(this.config.sorting, config.sorting);
    }
     var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        this.http.get('http://localhost:3009/api/auth/getstudents', { headers: headers })
            .subscribe(
            result => {
                if (result.json().error_code == 0) {
                   this.res = result.json().result;
                   this.students = this.res;
                    this.ng2TableData = this.students;
                      let filteredData = this.changeFilter(this.ng2TableData, this.config);
    let sortedData = this.changeSort(filteredData, this.config);
    this.rows = page && config.paging ? this.changePage(page, sortedData) : sortedData;
    this.length = sortedData.length;
                }
                else {
                    this.students = result.json().result;
                }
            })

  }
```

I had a very hard time working on it but no use...it says the error as 
Cannot read property 'match' of undefined.Can anyone please suggest some help..........

Comment: Looks like your `item[config.filtering.columnName]` does not exists. print your `item` to the console and your key `config.filtering.columnName` and see why this key is missing. What I have noticed you are using way too much of `any` type. Why? Typescript is a strongly typed language. Why not do that in proper way?

Comment: Oh..It worked finally,thanks Baumi...

Comment: How can i add a button to each column

Comment: You would have to edit ng-table.component.ts in the package. Create your edit buttons <td>'s and have them show conditionally based on some sort of 'delete' or 'edit' input flag. To notify the parent  component that the edit/delete was fired, emit the action event with an Output event. Rather create another question on SO.